# How to generate case class without options from View by Slick?

Tags: postgresql, slick

I have two tables, both with not null values.

```
CREATE TABLE data_raw
(
  id bigserial not null constraint data_raw_pkey primary key,
  title varchar(255) not null
  search_result_id varchar(255) not null constraint data_search_result_id_key unique
)
CREATE TABLE  data_annotated
(
  id bigserial not null constraint data_annotated_pkey primary key,
  id_match numeric(4,3) not null
  search_result_id varchar(255) not null
)
```

I have a view joining the two tables

```
CREATE VIEW data_test AS
  SELECT r.id, r.title, a.id_match, r.search_result_id
  FROM data_raw r JOIN data_annotated a ON r.search_result_id = a.search_result_id
```

All fields are not null, generated code for Tables have non optional fields. However generated class of the view has all fields optional. How can I achieve to generate non optional fields from Views? Using postgress.

```scala
case class DataTest(
  id: ID,
  title: Option[String] = None,
  idMatch: Option[scala.math.BigDecimal] = None,
  searchResultId: Option[String] = None) extends Node
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not a solution but I guess the generator looked at the schema definition.

```
select column_name, is_nullable
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS where table_name = 'data_test';

| column_name     | is_nullable |
|-----------------|-------------|
| id              | YES         |
| title           | YES         |
| id_match        | YES         |
|search_result_id | YES         |
```

At least I hope that explains why you are getting `Option` all the way.